# How do I see what song just played?

Tags: ios, music.app

I'm trying out Apple Music for the first time and confused by its interface. I've been listening to a "radio" station (e.g. Radio → Charting Now) and want to see what song just finished playing. Where should I look?

I expected to find a play queue like in Spotify and Google Play Music, but so far haven't found anything analogous.

Comment: What kind of „Radio“ stations are you listening? Internet Radio, one of the Apple stations within the Music app (in the Radio tab) or something else? If you are unsure, please add a screenshot.

Comment: From the home screen: Music → Radio → Charting Now